# String does not update its value on split

Tags: c++

I have a function that receives coordinates as a string "1.12 1.28". I have to split the string and assign both values to float variables (x = 1.12 and y = 1.28). The problem is that when I split the string to separate the values it stops assigning a new value to the string.

When I run the code below it prints the whole string and updates at every iteration.

```
void print_coordinates(string msg, char delim[2])
{
    cout << msg;
    cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    SerialIO s("/dev/cu.usbmodem1441");

    while(true) {
        print_coordinates(s.read(), " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

1.2 1.4

1.6 1.8

3.2 1.2

But when I run the code below it stops updating the string.

```
void print_coordinates(string msg, char delim[2])
{
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;

    vector<string> result;
    boost::split(result, msg, boost::is_any_of(delim));

    x = strtof((result[0]).c_str(), 0);
    y = strtof((result[1]).c_str(), 0);

    cout << x;
    cout << " ";
    cout << y;
    cout << "\n";

}

int main()
{
    SerialIO s("/dev/cu.usbmodem1441");

    while(true) {
        print_coordinates(s.read(), " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

1.2 1.4

1.2 1.4

1.2 1.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use boost, you can just use [boost::tokenizer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html).

But you don't need to use Boost to separate a string.
If your separator is a whitespace character `" "`, you can simply use std::stringsstream.

```
void print_coordinates(std::string msg)
{
    std::istringstream iss(msg);
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    iss >> x >> y;
    std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to specify your delimitor

```
void print_coordinates(std::string msg, char delim)
{
    std::istringstream iss(msg);
    std::vector<float> coordinates;
    for(std::string field; std::getline(iss, field, delim); ) 
    {
        coordinates.push_back(::atof(field.c_str()));
    }
    std::cout << "x = " << coordinates[0] << ", y = " << coordinates[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it made my code way easier, but my problem is still the same. Even if I use your method it keeps printing the same values over and over again, but if I print `msg` it prints the updated values.

Comment: Then it probably means your problem is elsewhere and does not come from print coordinate. Try to post code that reproduce the problem